# Testing a Spray route: why do I need to define an actorRefFactory: ActorSystem?

Tags: akka, scalatest, spray

I'm having a test code for checking a web service, and some of the inherited classes brings in `HttpService` (not sure, which one), requiring me to define an `actorRefFactory` reference within the test class.

Is there a better way to do this?

Scala 2.11.4, ScalaTest 2.2.1, Spray 1.3.2, Akka 2.3.6

```
class RestAPITest extends FlatSpec
  with Matchers
  with ScalatestRouteTest
  with SprayJsonSupport
  with MyRoute
{
  // Without this, we get:
  // <<
  //    Error:(48, 7) class RestAPITest needs to be abstract, since method actorRefFactory in trait HttpService of type => akka.actor.ActorRefFactory is not defined
  // <<
  //
  def actorRefFactory: ActorSystem = system

  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actorSystem is required by spray since it is based on Akka actors.  The idiomatic testing mechanism for spray would be to use the spray-testkit project.

From the [spray-testkit](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-testkit/%20spray-testkit) documentation:

The basic structure of a test built with spray-testkit is this (expression placeholder in all-caps):

```
REQUEST ~> ROUTE ~> check {
  ASSERTIONS
}
```

In this template REQUEST is an expression evaluating to an HttpRequest instance. Since both RouteTest traits extend the spray-httpx Request Building trait you have access to its mini-DSL for convenient and concise request construction.

ROUTE is an expression evaluating to a spray-routing Route. You can specify one inline or simply refer to the route structure defined in your service.

The final element of the ~> chain is a check call, which takes a block of assertions as parameter. In this block you define your requirements onto the result produced by your route after having processed the given request. Typically you use one of the defined “inspectors” to retrieve a particular element of the routes response and express assertions against it using the test DSL provided by your test framework. For example, with specs2, in order to verify that your route responds to the request with a status 200 response, you’d use the status inspector and express an assertion like this:

```
status mustEqual 200
```

Comment: Thanks. What I don't quite understand is why cannot ScalatestRouteTest provide a default for this and since normally such things are done via implicits in Scala (right?) why not here? Naming an abstract member just feels kind of non-scalaish.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a good answer to that question.  Might be worth reaching out to the mailing list to see what sort of answer you get.  It may be that there is another actor system that spray uses for internal business.  That would complicate the implicit declaration since you would have two ActorSystems.  It also may be the case that the authors determined that people would generally want to test with their own ActorSystems.  Hard to be sure without digging through the code though...

Comment: Exactly. Will just carry on. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

as the error said, you need an actorRefFactory for the actor to spawn in the HTTP service. So go ahead.